# MySQL Group by one column, but select all data

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database which contains lots of data. I would like to select all data, but Group by one column.

So for example:

```
column a | column b
example  | apple
example  | pear
example  | orange
example  | strawberry
```

In the example column A is a column which has duplicate values and needs to be grouped.
Column B however has different values, and I would like to select all these values.

In the end, I would like to get a query that results in:

```
example
- apple
- pear
- orange
- strawberry
```

Where the values of column B are in a jQuery accordion.

I've tried and searched for a couple of hours but still haven't found a way to do this.

**EDIT:**
I've manage to solve the problem using the answer Gordon provided. 
Using PHP I exploded the query results and with a while loop I collected all the data from the arrays.

It's working great now, thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks for editing my question, I was struggling to create columns in the editor :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can get what you want using `group_concat()`:

```
select a, group_concat(b)
from t
group by a;
```

This will create a list of "b"s for each a.  In your example:

```
example    apple,pear,orange,strawberry
```

You can change the separator using the `SEPARATOR` keyword.

EDIT:

You can use `group_concat()` multiple times:

```
select a, group_concat(b) as bs, group_concat(c) as cs
from t
group by a;
```

Or, combine it with `concat()`:

```
select a, group_concat(concat(b, ':', 'c')) as bcs
from t
group by a;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you that is working fine. However, I have got a few columns like Column b, so when I would group_concat them all, I will get alot of columns with comma seperated content. That's not really a problem, but I need to select them individually, without the commas.

is there any way to do to that in mysql? or should i just use php to explode the values?

Comment: Ok, so if I want to be able to get all data that belongs to the first item in column a, I will just have to explode all other columns in PHP and get the first value of them? Or is there a way to do this directly in mysql?

Comment: @KevinSleegers . . . If you only want one `b` value, then use one of the following:  `min(b)`, `max(b)`, `subsring_index(group_concat(b order by <whatever>), ',', 1)`.

Comment: I want them all, but with their own values. I guess it's a thing I'll have to do in PHP though.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it has helped me and it solved most of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

All SQL systems deal in tables: rectangles of data with rows and columns. Your question asks for a result set which isn't really a rectangle of data, in the sense that it contains "header" rows and "detail" rows.

```
 Example:    (header row)
   - apple   (detail row)
```

It's common practice to create such header / detail breakout in your client (php) software.

Pro tip:  Remember that if you don't specify ORDER BY, MySQL (and all SQLs) are permitted to return the information in your result in any convenient order.  Enlarging on Gordon's fine answer, then, you might want:

```
 SELECT a, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b, ':', 'c') ORDER BY b,c) AS bcs
   FROM t
  GROUP BY A
  ORDER BY A
```

I learned this the hard way when I helped write a SQL app that was really successful.  All the ordering worked great until we switched over to higher - capacity clustered access methods. Then lots of "default" ordering broke and our customers saw strange stuff until we fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

The example live of accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/WMUJ3/207/
Just implement in code below.  ;)

The code to mount data:

```
<html>

    <head>Your page</head>

    <body>

        <div class="accordion">
            <?php echo getData() ?>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>

<?php

function getData(){

    //This get the unique values of column a
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT column_a FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

        $html = "<h3>{$row->column_a}</h3>";

        //This get the values with column a some value
        $sql2 = "SELECT column_b FROM table WHERE column_a LIKE '%{$row->column_a}%'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

        $html .= '<div class="pane"><ul>';
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
            $html .= '<li>{$row2->column_b}</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul></div>';

    }

    return $html;

}

?>
```

Comment: Running iterated queries is a horrible suggestion.

Comment: yep, don't do this